# Google Cloud Hosted WordPress Site Only Loading Successfully Some of the Time

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a WordPress website that I'm hosting in a Compute Engine instance on Google Cloud, located at secondactwoman.com, and it is only loading successfully some of the time. Other times I will receive an error within WordPress that says "There has been a critical error on your website. Learn more about debugging in WordPress." or I will get an HTTP 500 error and the site won't load at all. I assume I've screwed something up in the Google Cloud setup. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry this is so vague, I'm very new to the Google Cloud Platform and I'm not even sure where to start looking. I've googled the problem in every way I can and still haven't found anything of use.

Comment: Usually for WordPress, the problem is memory, CPU or a PHP script error. Did you install Stackdriver on your instance? If not, install it so that errors are logged. https://www.jhanley.com/google-compute-stackdriver-logging-installation-setup-debugging/ If you did setup Stackdriver, post the logs for your Compute Engine instance.

Comment: 1/2) Have you encountered [this](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-the-500-internal-server-error-on-your-wordpress-website) link regarding

Comment: 2/2) "How to Fix the 500 Internal Server Error on Your WordPress Website" or [this](https://winningwp.com/fixing-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/) link, while googling?

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comments, usually it's an issue with memory or CPU. My guess is that you are using the 1 click setup from the GCP Marketplace, the default machine type for it should not give you any problems, but if you chose a smaller VM, you might wanna consider upgrading it. It would be nice to have the logs though. Try to install the [Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) if you can, and share the logs of the error with us once it happens again.